# LUIS Entity or Intent

Tags: c#, azure, nlp, azure-language-understanding

Should I use Entities or Intents for similar questions but different answer?
Example for searching an apartment:

- Is there an air conditioner? => Answer "Yes"
- How big is the kitchen?    => Answer *room plan*
- What is the rent?             => Answer *calculation of costs*
- How much does it cost?  => Answer *calculation of costs*
- What's the gross price?  => Answer *calculation of costs*

**First solution** would be to put everything in one Intent and make the following List-Entities:

```
AIR_CONDITIONER = {air conditioner, air conditioning, ... }
ROOM = {kitchen, living room, bath, ...}
COST= {rent, cost, price, gross price, ...}
```

Advantage, you don't have this much intents. 
Disadvantage, for every new Entity-Element e.g. 'net price' you have to edit the Entity-List. Also you have a problem with typos, you have to handle them in the code and LUIS can't help you with that.

**Second solution** would be to put everything in a separate Intent, without any Entity. 
So, there would be 3 Intents:

```
AIR_CONDITIONER_INTENT
ROOM_INTENT
COST_INTENT
```

Advantage, LUIS will recognize e.g. 'net price' without any configuration. 
Disadvantage, you will have a lot of intents maybe more then 80, which is not possible.

Comment: What is LUIS you mentioned?

Comment: I think, that the intent for this questions is the same - user wants to know more about the apartment. You may use the list entity, but it looks for the exact match, and this creates obstacles with plurals etc. You can try `phrase lists`, they tend to be more cognitive. There is no silver bullet for such tasks